# Data inserted in Website - security issue

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I have a security issue on one of my websites and I am quite unsure how to prevent this, as I never had a similar problem. I have a php driven webpage, and over night someone somehow managed to paste

```
<iframe src="http://<webaddress>.com/" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

right after the body tag into the php (!) file.

What would make something like that possible? And how do I prevent this?

Thanks for any help!

Maenny

Comment: There are number of questions that might help you:

Comment: There are number of questions that might help you: (1) Do you host all these web sites? (2) Are you using a fully patched web server and PHP engine? (3) Is it possible that another script on hosted on the server allows system commands to be run with arbitrary command line parameters?

Comment: (1) no I don't host them (2) I don't know about the patched server, (3) I had one htaccess-protected folder set to 775, because I have a sqlite-database in there that should be possible to write to when logged into the website. Concerning the other points - is there a method to find out if the system commands can be executed with arbitrary command-line params? Sorry, but I really don't have much experience in these things.

Comment: Probably the best course of action would be to notify the hosting service, because they may have other sites that have been targetted.

Comment: Sites should perform tough validation on input before passing it to the PHP system command. Unfortunately, there is no quick way to establish whether or not any site does this properly.

Comment: hm when googling about the problem, often the explanation seems to be that somehow the ftp-password has been stolen by malware, and that gives the access to change the site

Comment: Do you have access to logs ? if yes - check if there is any "strange" requests

Comment: Not a substitute for a proper answer, but there is good existing info in previous questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+hacked

Answer (score 2):

Many times this is the result of your FTP credentials being stolen. Change them, remove the malicious code, and try to always connect to your server over a secure connection. This is a common attack in joomla, wordpress and other popular CMSs; and it's usual to have many files (all your index.php files for example) attacked.

Comment: Do you know which file I have to search for the malicious code? I mean, like a script file that does not belong to my data and that executes the changes by itself?

Comment: Just search for the added html inside your files, remove it and that's it. It very likely they didn't upload anything.

Answer (score 1):

We've been seeing many plugins, extensions, etc. being used as the point of entry to a website.

Hackers are constantly trying to hide their "wares" so they may not infect all of your index files, just a few to try and "fly under the radar".

As far as removing that line, it's probably not going to look like what you see in the "view source" of your browser. It's going to be obfuscated (coded).

Without knowing your website or what you're running on there, ie., WordPress, Joomla, etc. it's difficult to tell you where to look for the obfuscated code, however, you might look in header.php files or whatever file is generating the code for your body tag. You might see script tags right after the body tag and you may have to scroll all the way to the end of the line with the body tag in order to see the malscript. Hackers like to do add lots of extra spaces to try and hide their malscript.

Then you'll have to see what files have been added to your site. Or, if you have a good backup, you might want to delete all the files on your site and restore them from backup. That might be the only way to find any backdoors. Backdoors are files hackers use to upload some of their other infected files. They can be PHP or Perl.

Last, you'll have to determine how it happened. Do you have access to your access logs? If so, scan them. Look for strings that don't look right. Sometimes you might search the logs for the string, "base64_decode" as hackers like to use that at times to upload their malicious code.

Keep all software: WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, Zen Cart, osCommerce, etc. updated at all times. Also keep any add-ons, etc. updated as well.